# jQuery replaceWith, append, prepend not working

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, append

I am trying to prepend something to a li, hosted inside a `#container #boxes #third li a` but it isn't quite working.

I am using the following code:

```
$('#container #boxes #third li a').append(kevintext);
```

But whenever I do that, nothing happens. You can see the code in action at my [testing page](http://nth.brandonwang.org/stuhf2/) here.

Because that didn't work, I tried something else: to replace a span inside my footer with other text (so people with JavaScript disabled won't see "hover over me" and try to hover).

I used the following code:

```
$('#footer span').replaceWith('<i>For design info, mouse over me.</i>');
```

That didn't work either, so I am thinking this probably has something to do with my code, and possibly one fix will solve both problems?

Please help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you took the time to make a simple test case

Comment: I just ran $('#third li a').append('test'); and it added test to all 3 list items in the last block just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have should work. The main reason it probably isn't is because (at least by the quick look I took at assets/script.js) you are trying to run this outside of $(document).ready() - without wrapping your code in this function (which you did do for another part) the elements will not have been created yet, so at that point nothing will happen.

Comment: Oh; I always thought that once document.ready was ran, it meant the page was finished and therefore you couldn't add anything to it.

Comment: That would make a lot of websites out there impossible to do :) All document.ready does is wait for the DOM tree to be ready so you can do selections on the elements in your page. Since you're adding content in a specific place, you have to wait for the DOM to be ready so you can find the specific place.